# How to make this jQuery code more simple and effective

Tags: javascript

I have follow two functions here which working great!
As you can see these two functions are almost the same, except the code which comes below the last comment in each function.

How do I make that more simple. Could I make a code-"holder" - Where I only include a part of a code from another file? So I don't have too have the "same" code in each functions?

Should I use some kind of classes or? - I have never worked with classes.

/// Function (add_new_field)

```
$(document).on("click", '.add_new_field', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

        var flex0 = $(this);
        var flex1 = $(this).parent().closest('div'); 
        var flex2 = $(flex1).parent().closest('div'); 
        var flex3 = $(flex2).parent().closest('div');
        var flex4 = $(flex3).parent().closest('div'); 
        var flex5 = $(flex4).parent().closest('div');
        var flex6 = $(flex5).parent().closest('div');

        /*console.log(
        ' -> WrapID:'+flex6.attr('id')+
        ' -> accordionContentID:'+flex5.attr('id')+
        ' -> acContentBoxID:'+flex4.attr('id')+
        ' -> acChildBoxID:'+flex3.attr('id')+
        ' -> acBabyBoxID:'+flex2.attr('id')+
        ' -> SecondID:'+flex1.attr('id')+
        ' -> FirstID:'+flex0.attr('id')
        );*/

        var wrapID = flex6.attr('id'); // wrapID
        var accordionContentID = flex5.attr('id');
        var acContentBoxID = flex4.attr('id'); // sharedID
        var acChildBoxID = flex3.attr('id'); // langID
        var acBabyBoxID = flex2.attr('id'); // langID
        var SecondID = flex1.attr('id'); // OLD : AddLangBoxID
        var FirstID = flex0.attr('id'); //  OLD : add_new_fieldID

       // there is a lot more code here...

   )};
```

/// Function (del_field)

```
    $(document).on("click", '.del_field', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        var flex0 = $(this);
        var flex1 = $(this).parent().closest('div'); 
        var flex2 = $(flex1).parent().closest('div');
        var flex3 = $(flex2).parent().closest('div'); 
        var flex4 = $(flex3).parent().closest('div'); 
        var flex5 = $(flex4).parent().closest('div'); 
        var flex6 = $(flex5).parent().closest('div'); 

        var wrapID = flex6.attr('id'); // wrapID
        var accordionContentID = flex5.attr('id');
        var acContentBoxID = flex4.attr('id'); // sharedID
        var acChildBoxID = flex3.attr('id'); // langID
        var acBabyBoxID = flex2.attr('id'); // langID
        var SecondID = flex1.attr('id'); // OLD : AddLangBoxID
        var FirstID = flex0.attr('id'); //  OLD : add_new_fieldID


        // there is a lot more code her

       )};
```

How could I make something like this.

/// I want to include this code into the functions. So I don't have to write it twice.

```
        var flex0 = $(this);
        var flex1 = $(this).parent().closest('div'); 
        var flex2 = $(flex1).parent().closest('div');
        var flex3 = $(flex2).parent().closest('div'); 
        var flex4 = $(flex3).parent().closest('div'); 
        var flex5 = $(flex4).parent().closest('div'); 
        var flex6 = $(flex5).parent().closest('div'); 

        var wrapID = flex6.attr('id'); // wrapID
        var accordionContentID = flex5.attr('id');
        var acContentBoxID = flex4.attr('id'); // sharedID
        var acChildBoxID = flex3.attr('id'); // langID
        var acBabyBoxID = flex2.attr('id'); // langID
        var SecondID = flex1.attr('id'); // OLD : AddLangBoxID
        var FirstID = flex0.attr('id'); //  OLD : add_new_fieldID
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can use a while loop to loop through the vars (flex 0 to 6).

Comment: thats correct. But what If I want to use the same code in each function, without I have write the same in each function - Is there some way I can write it once and include it, in each function?

Comment: `var accordionContentID = $(flex4).parent().closest('div').attr('id');` you could do something like this in a `_for or while loop_`

Comment: I know that. Lets say, that the code was something else. But I want to include instead of writing it two times

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for codereview and thus belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I asking for a way to write the code more simple. Read the description please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something like classes in javascript, your best bet is to use prototyping, since javascript doesn't have classes.

In this case, I'm not sure what your code does, so prototyping might not be the best answer. Your other option is to encapsulate all of your variable definitions in another function, and call that function in both of your click functions. It would return an object with attributes, rather that a bunch of `var`s.

```
var myVarFn = function(){
    var returnObject = {};

    returnObject.flex0 = $(this);
    returnObject.flex1 = $(this).parent().closest('div'); 
    ...

    returnObject.wrapID = flex6.attr('id'); // wrapID
    ...

    return returnOBject
}
```

And to use it in click, with `this` defined the same as in the scope of the click function:

```
$(document).on("click", '.del_field', function(e) {
    var dataObject = myVarFn.call(this);

    //Other code
};
```

And in the other click event,

```
$(document).on("click", '.add_new_field', function(e) {
    var dataObject = myVarFn.call(this);

    //Other code
};
```

You will have to modify your other code to use `dataObject.flex0` instead of `flex0` and so on.

Comment: The codes works just fine! :) I just want to know how I could make a xxx.js file, where I from ex. line 4-20 include that code into my function. - So I don't have to write the same it into both functions

Comment: That's what I'm describing. You can call myVarFn once in each click function, and have it define all of your variables as attributes on an object. I edited my answer to make this a bit more clear.

Comment: I get an error: SyntaxError: Expected token '(' in line: "function myVarFn = function(){" . Otherwise I think I understand now :)

Comment: I changed it to: function myVarFn(){ . Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Oops, that should be either `function myVarFn()` or `var myVarFn = function()`. Fixed my example.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global object

```
var allId = new Object();
```

And a function that can be called whenever needed..

```
function getAllIDs(el) {
    var id = ["wrapID", "accordionContentID", "acContentBoxID", "acChildBoxID", "acBabyBoxID", "SecondID", "FirstID"];
    var flex;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            flex = $(el).parent().closest('div');
        } else {
            flex = $(flex).parent().closest('div');
        }
        allId.id[i] = $(flex).parent().closest('div').attr('id');
    }
}
```

Further, on jQuery event you can call `getAllIDs` function

```
$(document).on("click", '.add_new_field', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    getAllIDs(this);
});
```

[***More details about `javascript objects`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)